# Adjective for a work that needs no significant support, clarification, or defense?

Tags: single-word-requests

I vaguely remember using a word before that describes a work (general document, proof, program, etc.) as being so clear, complete, and high-quality (etc.) that it requires no serious explanation, clarification, or defense.

*Cogent* comes to mind, but I feel like there was a more more broadly relevant to larger works -- which could also be applied to programs that are very readable, easy-to-understand, and therefore easy to validate, etc..

Comment: Note that I'm posting an answer for a word that just came to mind and will suffice for my current need ... But, I still have the sense there's a better word out there!

Comment: "self-evident", "clear", "lucid" (less good but has situational uses), "self-explanatory" , "speaks for itself", "concise"

Comment: self-authenticating?

Comment: "comprehensive"?

Comment: Curious as to why this question is being downvoted -- if there are no words that match the concept, isn't the answer just, "there are no words that match this concept?"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[Coherent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coherent) just came to mind:

> 1) Unified; sticking together; making up a whole.
>
> **2) Orderly, logical and
>   consistent.**
>
> 3) Aesthetically ordered.
>
> 4) Having a natural or due agreement
>    of parts; harmonious: a coherent design.

That 2nd definition pretty closely matches what I was trying to think of. But, I feel like there's still a better word out there.

More on the "completeness" side is *comprehensive.* (Thanks, tenebris2020.)  Though, it doesn't really include the logic, orderliness, and consistency I was looking for.

<sup>(I wish I were thinking more *coherently* today ...)</sup>

Comment: svigden, I'm sorry to point out that neither *cogent* nor *coherent* comes close to the description you gave; neither generally nor specifically in that 2nd definition of *coherent*.

Check that with your favourite thesauruses…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin It's lacking in a sense of completeness, but it has the *orderliness, logicalness, and consistency* I was referring to ... So, no. You're just wrong. Sorry ... I mean, unless you're point is that *it's not **exactly** the word I'm looking for* -- in which case, *yes, I already ceded that in the answer.* But, to say it doesn't even "come close" ... you're just mistaken.

Comment: Marking this as the "correct" answer, for lack of other answers...

Comment: Thanks, svigden, and whatever your native language, neither "cogent" nor "coherent" describes any work that needs no significant support, clarification, or defense. It's entirely possible that such works will be both "cogent" and "coherent" but that will be pure co-incidence.

FYI, the Question was prolly down-voted because there was no research.

Comment: @Robbie You'd think with "no research" that someone would have mentioned some obvious oversight in the comments... In any case, thanks for your feedback. And I apologize for my snark. In lieu of a more fitting answer, *coherent* served my purpose in conjunction with *comprehensive*.